# How do I remove a message that Mac users receive when they log on to a server (Windows Server 2003)

Tags: mac-osx, windows-server-2003-r2

When Mac users connect to my network, they receive a message via dialog box saying:
Message from server 
Welcome MAC user...bet you feel special!

Hilarious and all, but I'd like to do away with it. It was put in place by a previous, disgruntled admin.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using File Server for Macintosh servers on Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Windows server running File Server for Macintosh run the following:

`macfile /loginmessage`

You can read all `macfile` commands in [this Microsoft KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/148128)